# Добавление в BindingList значения из другого потока

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня есть метод который возвращает объект и за кулисами он использует другой поток. Сам метод вручную не вызывается и поток вручную не создается. Есть возможность только подписаться на событие и обработать результат который пришел. Однако при попытке обработать результат и добавить его в BindingList выдается ошибка о том, что к BindingList идет попытка доступа из другого потока. Подскажите как это можно исправить?

Comment: В приведенных мною ссылках есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Используйте `BeginInvoke` в своем подписчике. Т.е. добавляйте элемент в `BindingList` внутри `BeginInvoke`

Comment: И где в BindingList BeginInvoke? Это же не контрол по типу лейбла.

Comment: Да, но вы можете взять любой контрол и вызвать `BeginInvoke` на нем

Comment: Проблема в том, что их нет, есть просто класс и его BindingList, который я хочу заполнить.

Comment: Ага, тогда вам нужно в этом классе иметь диспетчер и добавлять запись с помощью него. Диспетчер можно получить так: `var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`, но вам нужно получить его в форме и передать в свой класс. Потом просто вызываете `dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);`

Comment: Где создается ваш этот класс, в котором BindingList?

Comment: В Program, через IoС контейнер

Comment: Сам класс это 
public class MainPresenter : BasePresenter<IMainView>{ private BindingList<object> objects }
IMainView имеет только SetDataSource(BindingList<object> objects)

Comment: Вот в Program значит вам нужно получить диспетчер и передать его в свой класс

Comment: Хорошо, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Имхо, вопрос закрыт неправильно. Он не про доступ к GUI из другого потока, а про работу с BindingList (который, оказывается, не позволяет это напрямую).

Comment: Посмотрите в [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3471983/5045688) теме ответы bporter и Marc Gravell.

Comment: Кого это волнует, GUI не GUI, есть слово поток, то дубликат =D

Comment: Ответ от Marc Gravell похоже то, что я искал, спасибо.